# AEM:: dropdown select values and checkbox not being saved

Tags: aem

I have added a new tab to page properties. The tab consists of a multifieldpanel (acs-aem-commons bundle). I am trying to add a textfield, a dropdown and a number of checkboxes. The issue is that when I select the value under dropdown and select the checkboxes, everything looks fine but when I open the Page properties again it doesn't look like the values have been saved. Here is the code:

```
<tab_xxxx_suppression xmlns:social="http://www.adobe.com/social/1.0" jcr:primaryType="cq:Panel" title="Suppression">
<items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
<idsuppress jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget" fieldDescription="Press + to add more" fieldLabel="Configure ID card suppress" name="./idsuppress" width="1000" xtype="multifield">
<fieldConfig jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget" name="./fieldConfig" xtype="multifieldpanel">
<items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
<providedValue jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget" allowBlank="false" fieldDescription="Please provide the value for option selected above" fieldLabel="Provide value here" key="providedValue" labelStyle="width:150px" name="./providedValue" xtype="textfield"/>
<selectList jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget" defaultValue="0" fieldLabel="Business Rules" name="./suppress" type="select" xtype="selection">
<options jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
<one jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" text="Vanity URL" value="Vanity"/>
<two jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" text="PV/RC" value="PVRC"/>
<three jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" text="SA/OI" value="SAOI"/>
<four jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" text="Market Type" value="Market"/>
<five jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" text="Product Code" value="Product"/>
<six jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" text="Div Code" value="Div"/>
<seven jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" text="State of Issue" value="State"/>
<eight jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" text="Government Program Code" value="Government"/>
</options>
</selectList>
<suppressOptions jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget" title="Selection Options" xtype="dialogfieldset">
<items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
<whole jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget" fieldLabel="Suppress View ID Card Functionality" labelStyle="width:240px" name="./whole" type="checkbox" width="auto" xtype="selection"/>
<order jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget" fieldLabel="Suppress Order ID card Functionality" labelStyle="width:239px" name="./order" type="checkbox" width="auto" xtype="selection"/>
<view jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget" fieldLabel="Suppress View ID Card Functionality" labelStyle="width:238px" name="./view" type="checkbox" width="auto" xtype="selection"/>
</items>
</suppressOptions>
</items>
</fieldConfig>
</idsuppress>
</items>
</tab_xxxx_suppression>
```

Answer (score 0):

I try your code in my env and I think I found the problem (or problems):

1. Since you define the property as a multifield, this will be stored as an json object. So each of the item's property will be json keys (no properties itself), you need to specify "key" attribute and not "name".
2. I don't know why the fieldConfig don't like the dialogfieldset, causing the exclussion of the checkboxes.

Finally the below code worked fine for me:

```
        <idsuppress jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget" fieldDescription="Press + to add more"
        fieldLabel="Configure ID card suppress" name="./idsuppress" width="1000"
        xtype="multifield">
        <fieldConfig jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget" xtype="multifieldpanel">
            <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                <providedValue jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                    allowBlank="false" fieldDescription="Please provide the value for option selected above"
                    fieldLabel="Provide value here" key="providedValue" labelStyle="width:150px"
                    name="./providedValue" xtype="textfield" />
                <selectList jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget" defaultValue="0"
                    fieldLabel="Business Rules" key="suppress" type="select" xtype="selection">
                    <options jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                        <one jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" text="Vanity URL"
                            value="Vanity" />
                        <two jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" text="PV/RC" value="PVRC" />
                        <three jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" text="SA/OI"
                            value="SAOI" />
                        <four jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" text="Market Type"
                            value="Market" />
                        <five jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" text="Product Code"
                            value="Product" />
                        <six jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" text="Div Code" value="Div" />
                        <seven jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" text="State of Issue"
                            value="State" />
                        <eight jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" text="Government Program Code"
                            value="Government" />
                    </options>
                </selectList>

                <whole jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                    fieldLabel="Suppress View ID Card Functionality" labelStyle="width:240px"
                    key="whole" type="checkbox" width="auto" xtype="selection" />
                <order jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                    fieldLabel="Suppress Order ID card Functionality" labelStyle="width:239px"
                    key="order" type="checkbox" width="auto" xtype="selection" />
                <view jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget" fieldLabel="Suppress View ID Card Functionality"
                    labelStyle="width:238px" key="view" type="checkbox" width="auto"
                    xtype="selection" />

            </items>
        </fieldConfig>
    </idsuppress>
```

Hope this help you!